# Is there a way to cast this enum to proper type

Tags: c#, enums

I have a user control, which in effect a wrapper over dropdownlist.

I set a type like this:

```
public Type ListType { get; set; }
```

Then try to create the drop down list items based on this type.

Here's my first attempt:

```
    void SetOptions()
    {
        DropDownList.Items.Clear();

        var options = Enum.GetNames(ListType).ToList();

        options.ThrowNullOrEmpty("options");

        foreach (var s in options)
        {
            var e = Enum.Parse(ListType, s) as Enum;

            var item = new ListItem(e.Description(), s);

            DropDownList.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

However, I wondered if this could be done like this:

```
    void SetOptions()
    {
        DropDownList.Items.Clear();

        var options = Enum.GetValues(ListType); // need to cast this to type of ListType

        foreach (var o in options)
        {
            var item = new ListItem(o.Description(), o.ToString());

            DropDownList.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

Just can't work out how I get the list of values cast to the correct enum type.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
void SetOptions()
{
    DropDownList.Items.Clear();

    var options = Enum.GetValues(ListType); // need to cast this to type of ListType

    foreach (var o in options)
    {
        var item = new ListItem(o.Description(), o.ToString());
        item.Tag = o;

        DropDownList.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Then you can get the type from the Tag property of whatever list item is selected.